# Integration Test with Transactional

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I have the following scenario/system.
A Rest Service proposal, behind the Spring security configuration, with Spring JPA and a postgres DB.

Now my scenario makes a 
login of a user 1
logout of user 1
login of user 1
make a request on a resource
logout of user 1
login of user 2
make a request on a other resource
logout of user 2

This all on a test method (I know it can be wrong doing that).
Now that was confusing me is that he had some encryption/decryption methods to retrieve user and they're fields. Now what I saw was that on the firs login of 1 the user goes through the decryption code (this is OK), after in the second login of user 1 we don't goes through the decryption code (but the user was logged in). (this is a little bit strange, I has expected that the user goes though the decryption code), after that by accessing the resource also user 2 is decrypted (this is correct).
But by logging in the user 2 the user don't pass on the decryption code (and I have an exception because the fields that normaly are encrypted, now are decrypted) The exception can be OK, but not the fact that the fields are decrypted.

Now the exception is thrown only when I set the test under @Transactional.
When I make the test not @Transactional then the behavior sames to be correct (evry time by login the user is decrypted.)
Now I think: "it is logical that the test does not be @transactional", but I have a bit fear that I have a caching problem: can this be? I dont'have any caching configuration (only for ACL, not for user management). 
Also the second level cache of hibernate is turned off.

Is there a way to find out if some caching or inmemory strenght are intrcate?

Txs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your actual code and configuration, I can't really assess exactly what is going on; however, I can provide you the following general information...

If you are simulating a use case that models different external connections to your application (i.e., two independent users connecting to your application via a REST API), then you will not want to annotate your test method with `@Transactional`.

Annotating a test method with `@Transactional` causes **all** of the method invocations within your test method to be executed within the *same* transaction [0]. Thus, any items stored in the first-level cache by JPA will be cached across method invocations within the scope of your test method.

Hope this helps!

Sam

[0] This statement is based on the assumption that none of the methods invoked directly or indirectly by your test method are configured to run within a new transaction.

Comment: Txs for you're feed-back. You give me a bit assurance that that what I'm doing is in direction of the right way. Txs :)